# Empty directory when generating Cloud Endpoints PHP client with Google APIs Client Generator

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

I'm trying to generate a PHP client for my Google Cloud Endpoints API using the Google APIs [Client Generator](https://github.com/google/apis-client-generator) but it just creates an empty directory instead.

The command I'm using looks like:

```
generate_library --language=php --language_variant=stable --output_dir=/path/php-client --input=/path/myApi-v1.json
```

It seems to work when I change the language to csharp and java. I turned on the verbose flag and don't see any errors, only tracing messages like:

```
DEBUG:codegen:Create: myMethod, parent=update
DEBUG:codegen:Schema.Create: updateRequestContent => MyMessage
DEBUG:codegen:DataTypeFromJson: add MyMessage to cache
```

Searching around I see [someone at the AppEngine sub Reddit posted](https://www.reddit.com/r/AppEngine/comments/33mo59/cloud_endpoints_client_php_autogenerator/) a similar issue with no response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried again and changed the `--language_variant` argument from `stable` to `1.1.4` and it now works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I used another approach:

1. downloaded the zip from 
   https://github.com/google/apis-client-generator
2. Extracted the zip file in a directory (i named it client-generator)
3. Executed the generate.sh script available in the extracted files.

`/path/client-generator/generate.sh --input=/path/rest.json --language=php  --output_dir=/path/output`

The APICLassName.php file is generated